# What is the DNA sequences between two Inverted Repeats called?

Tags: genetics, dna, terminology, chromosome

I would like to know some rules about the nomenclature of Inverted Repeats DNA sequences. More in detail, I want to know what is the name of sequences between two inverted repeats.

For example, I have two genes A and B in this order: A, B, -A. The gene A is inverted duplicated and forms an inverted repeat with gene B in the middle. What do I call this gene B?

Here below are some names I found or that I thought, however, I don't consider them a good choice. Could you suggest some other names?

"intervening sequence", "in-between", "inserted", "separating", "spacer", "non-palindromic spacer", "loop", "gap".

In Wikipedia, they used the name "intervening sequence".
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_repeat

[image]

Comment: Welecome to SE Biology. Come si chiama, como se llama, Wie heißt, comment s'appelle. But in English is is **What**, not How.

Comment: There is no "rule" or even convention, as you found from Wikipedia. Such sequences are not sufficiently important (and have no general function) to have been given a name. Intervening sequence is a *description*, but as it is the long form of *intron*, I wouldn't use it. For suggestions on how to describe it (there are problems with all of yours), SE English Language & Usage would seem more appropriate. However you will need to give an example sentence there, which should relate to the specific circumstances.

Comment: To add to David's points, "inverted repeats" typically described very short sequences. Even so-called "long inverted repeats" are just tens of bp long. Since you have designated sequences **A** and **B** to be *genes*, it would be better to described your system as "gene B flanked by inverted copies of gene A", or something like that.

Comment: Thank you David and acvill, both comments were very useful. Yes, unfortunately, I have some long Inverted repeats with many genes and kilobases long which are not common and not well described (named).
I want to name them to describe a property that I think these sequences might have. I think I will use the term "internal sequences" or "sequences flanked by internal repeats" as acvill suggested.

Comment: I'll add that most green-plant chloroplast genomes contain a large inverted repeat (~10-76 kb). The chloroplast genome is circular, and the two intervening regions are creatively named the Large Single Copy and the Small Single Copy.